# insert doesn't permanently change map?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a member variable of this class that is `set<pair<string,map<string,int> > > setLabelsWords;` which is a little convoluted but bear with me. In a member function of the same class, I have the following code:

```
pair<map<string,int>::iterator,bool> ret;

for (auto j:setLabelsWords) {
  if (j.first == label) {
    for (auto k:words) {
      ret = j.second.insert(make_pair(k,1));
      if (ret.second == false) {
        j.second[k]++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

"words" is a set of strings and "label" is a string. So basically it's supposed to insert "k" (a string) and if k is already in the map, it increments the int by 1. The problem is it works until the outermost for loop is over. If I print j.second's size right before the last bracket, it will give me a size I expect like 13, but right outside the last bracket the size goes back to 7, which is what the size of the map is initially before this code block runs. I am super confused why this is happening and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (auto j:setLabelsWords) {
```

This iterates over the container ***by value***. This is the same thing as if you did:

```
class Whatever { /* something in here */ };

void changeWhatever(Whatever w);

// ...

{
   Whatever w;

   changewhatever(w);
}
```

Whatever `changewhatever` does to `w`, whatever modifications are made, are made to a copy of `w`, because it gets passed by value, to the function.

In order to correctly update your container, you must iterate by reference:

```
for (auto &j:setLabelsWords) {
```

Comment: Ah I see! Follow up q: the compiler now throws an error because for some reason it treats j.second as a const, so I can't modify it with insert or []. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Looks like your container is a `std::set`. Values in a set cannot be modified. After all, a set orders it's contents, and modifying values in a set might change the relative order of its contents, hence set values are const. Use a different container. The nice thing about containers is their uniform methods, so your code will unlikely need any changes. Just switch containers.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for (auto j:setLabelsWords) {
> ```

This creates a **copy** of each element. All the operations you perform on `j` affect that copy, not the original element in `setLabelsWords`.

Normally, you would just use a **reference**:

```
for (auto&& j:setLabelsWords) {
```

However, due to the nature of a `std::set`, this won't get you far, because a `std::set`'s elements cannot be modified freely via iterators or references to elements, because that would allow you to create a set with duplicates in it. The compiler will not allow that.

Here's a pragmatic solution: Use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::set`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::map<std::string,int>>> setLabelsWords;
```

You will then be able to use the reference approach explained above.

---

If you need `std::set`'s uniqueness and sorting capabilities later on, you can either apply `std::sort` and/or `std::unique` on the `std::vector`, or create a new `std::set` from the `std::vector`'s elements.

Comment: Pretty sure it's only one `&` if you want a reference.

Comment: @melpomene: In this case, it's equivalent, but `&&` automatically translates to `const&` if the code ever changes. Using `auto&&` in range-based `for` loops is often considered good practice.

Comment: @ChristianHackl when I changed it, it turned into a const and now I can't modify the map (with insert or [])... is there any way around this?

Comment: @newtothis: I just realised now that you've got a `std::set`, so you cannot freely modify elements. I'll have to adapt the answer to that.

Comment: @newtothis: Added an alternative solution.